# Special rhombii

Tags: number-sequence

There are two parts to this puzzle, but I am posting the other part tagged with ‘mathematics’ because it isn’t really a number sequence problem.
Part I
Find the next number in the sequence:
1,2,3,7,16,65,?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sequence in OEIS, which makes it rather easy!

> https://oeis.org/A000278
>  0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 16, 65, 321, 4546, 107587
>  It's a bit like the Fibonacci series, but instead of $a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2)$, it's $a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2)^2$

Comment: So did you get it with or without OEIS?

Comment: With, I'm afraid. I often check as a way to get ideas. It doesn't usually solve it.